# Accessing last inserted row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

On my db-server i am inserting data in a table having a auto increment field say 'id'. Now i want to use the value of this last inserted 'id' in subsequent steps. I can use this:-

```
  select * from table_name order by id desc limit 1;
```

But the problem here is, it is a server and many more insertions could be happening and there could be a case where i try to retrieve the data with the query i mentioned and get a different id ie. between my insert and select there could be some other insert and i wont get the value i inserted. Any way in which this could be addressed.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks straightforward :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html Depending on how you connect to the database, your library might have this functionality implemented out of the box, but the underlying mysql engine is surely capable of providing this Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this

```
mysql_insert_id(&mysql);
```

as its basic structure are

```
mysql_insert_id ([ resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

or in mysql use

```
   SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

**here is the ref links**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: can i use ` SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` direct in insert query?

Comment: @Irfan what you mean direct in insert Query ? explain what you want ?

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(colid) From tablename;
```

heres the [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Answer (score 4):

call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function immediately after insertion and save id somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Use this **mysql_insert_id()**

It  returns the AUTO_INCREMENT ID generated from the previous INSERT operation.

This function returns 0 if the previous operation does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT ID, or FALSE on MySQL connection failure.

Answer (score 2):

you can get the id if you call  LAST_INSERT_ID() function immediately after insertion and then you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

For any last inserted record will be get through **mysql_insert_id()**
If your table contain any AUTO_INCREMENT column it will return that Value.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test(emsg,etime) values ('inserted',now())");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
$last_id=mysql_insert_id();
echo $last_id;
?>
```