# Is there a way to get the date of the last inserted row?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mail` varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `reg_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

This is my query in the php code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`psw`) VALUES ('".$email."','".$psw."')";
  $_SESSION["id"] = mysqli_insert_id($db_con);
  // get the date of this row and put it in $_SESSION["regdate"]
```

Comment: Maybe you can refer on this old post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770600/mysql-select-the-last-inserted-row-easiest-way).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600527/accessing-last-inserted-row-in-mysql

Comment: Do you have that field within your table and are you saving that too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Change your insert statement slightly:

```
$currentDate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");//Get current date
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`psw`,`reg_date`) VALUES ('".$email."','".$psw."', '.$currentDate.')";//Save date, email and password to database
$_SESSION["id"] = mysqli_insert_id($db_con);//Get ID of the last row
$_SESSION["regdate"] = $currentDate;//Save it in session
```

### IMPORTANT

Although you are searching how to insert current date in database and `$_SESSION` array, you have much bigger problem. Your insert statement is vulnerable to the SQL Injection attack, meaning your application has security issue. Instead of using string concatenating, use `PDO` classes and something what is called prepared statements.

Example:

```
$currentDate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");//Get current date
$sql = "INSERT INTO users SET email=?, psw=?, reg_date = ?";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($email, $psw, $currentDate));
$_SESSION["id"] = mysqli_insert_id($db_con);//Get ID of the last row
$_SESSION["regdate"] = $currentDate;//Save it in session
```

It will work :)

Comment: Thanks, Why this is not secure? : $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with `mysqli_real_escape_string`, BUT it is "obsoleted" approach AND what will happen if you forget to call this function (usually this happens to developers). Also by using PDO, it is automatically performed, and that saves you time, efforts, and code maintenance is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

you may simply use `mysqli_insert_id` and select the row you've inserted

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`psw`) VALUES ('".$email."','".$psw."')";
mysqli_query($db_con, $query);
$_SESSION["id"] = mysqli_insert_id($db_con);

$query = "SELECT reg_date FROM `users` WHERE id='{$_SESSION["id"]}'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_con, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
print_r($row);
```

or you can insert current datetime, this way you do not have to query again to get the timestamp.

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`,`psw`, reg_date) VALUES ('".$email."','".$psw."', '".$dt."')";
mysqli_query($db_con, $query);
echo $dt; // last date you have inserted.
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply run a query after insertion to get the date

```
query = "SELECT `reg_date` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $_SESSION["id"]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get id for last inserted row

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($db_con);
```

Then, execute select query

```
select reg_date from users where id = $last_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below, make sure id should be auto increment

```
SELECT reg_date FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1
```